# Rails-Backbone Model save issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

This page is to edit the account information.

Template file,

```
<input type="text" id="account_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" value="<%=account.name%>"/>
<input type="text" id="account_company_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" value="<%=account.company_name%>"/>
<a id="account_next_btn" class="btn" role="button">Next</a>
```

view file,

```
events:
    'click #account_next_btn': "updateAccount"

updateAccount: (e)->
    e.preventDefault()
    @account.save({"name": @$el.find("#account_name").val(),"company_name": @$el.find("#account_company_name").val()})
```

ok, this works fine. it sends the updated input form parameters.

the thing i'm curious is, there should be a better way, not setting the updated values manually like my code.

in rails `backbone:scaffold` it doesn't have this kind of code.

it just

```
@model.save()
```

that is all they do.

but in my code, if i just call

```
@account.save()
```

it sends the parameter, that not have been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s because Backbone by default doesn’t include any kind of data binding library. Data binding lets you keep a model attribute synced with a form field value.

`Backbone-Rails` includes the simple `backbone_datalink.js`, which sets up a simple form binding when you create the scaffold.

There are many other binding plugins that work with Backbone, such as [`Backbone.ModelBinder`](https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder) and [`Rivets.js`](http://www.rivetsjs.com/).